# spring social twitter jsp cannot read List <Tweet>

Tags: spring-mvc, twitter, jstl, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social Twitter to fetch search result from twitter REST APIs.

I am getting the search result but while displaying it in JSP, it does not work.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws IOException{
     ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView("home");

    SearchResults results = twitter.searchOperations().search("#ithump");
    List<Tweet> tweet = results.getTweets();
    mov.addObject("tweets", tweet);


    return  mov;
}
```

JSP Display:

```
    <c:forEach items="${tweets}" var="tweet">
    <li><img src="${tweet.profileImageUrl}" align="middle"/><c:out value="${tweet.createdAt}"/><br/><c:out value="${tweet.text}" escapeXml="false"/></li>
</c:forEach>
```

I just see an empty home page. Any suggestion if we need to parse List  separately or send it to JSP in different format/view?

Thanks,

Comment: Three things: 1) Make sure your `test` method is being executed. 2) Make sure your `tweet` list is not empty. 3) Make sure there's no other *tweets* object in page, session or application scope.

Comment: I have a similar problem. The problem for me is that the tweets list is empty. However, why I am getting an empty tweet list when searching a query?

Comment: Mahsa, My problem got resolved after rebuild. no code change. It might be related to the twitter API connection. thanks